# It is necessary to make checks in the function of adding an edge to the graph

Tags: c++, graph

I need to check that:

1) I do not insert an existing edge
that is, if I have 5 vertices in the graph - the indexes from 0 to 4 then I can not add a reverse by the indexes (0, 6) for example

2) Check to avoid inserting the same vertices
but I can not figure out how to do it right

My Code:

```
bool Graph::addEdge(const Edge& edge)
{
   if (edge.mStartIndex == edge.mEndIndex)
      return false;

  //if (mVertexList[edge.mEndIndex] != edge.mStartIndex)
    {
     mVertexList[edge.mStartIndex].emplace_back(edge.mEndIndex, edge.mWeight);
     mVertexList[edge.mEndIndex].emplace_back(edge.mStartIndex, edge.mWeight);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Edge:

```
struct Edge
{
  Edge(VertexIndex startIndex, VertexIndex endIndex, float weight);

  VertexIndex mStartIndex;
  VertexIndex mEndIndex;
  float mWeight;
};

 struct AdjacentVertex
{
    AdjacentVertex(VertexIndex index, float weight);

    VertexIndex mIndex;
    float mWeight;
};

class Graph
{
public:
   using AdjacencyList = std::vector<AdjacentVertex>;
   Graph(VertexIndex numVertices);

   VertexIndex numVertices() const;
   const AdjacencyList& adjacencyList(VertexIndex index) const;

   bool addEdge(const Edge& edge);
   void removeEdge(const Edge& edge);

   private:
     using VertexList = std::vector<AdjacencyList>;
     VertexList mVertexList;
};
```

Comment: Hi, we need to know definition of your `mVertexList`.

Comment: @Yola  I UPD my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To check if an edge number is not too high you can do the following:

   ```
   if (edge.mStartIndex >= numVertices() || edge.mEndIndex >= numVertices()) 
   {
       // Handle situation when edge number is out of bound
   }
   ```
2. You can check if as adjacency list already contains this edge by using [find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

   ```
   auto it = std::find_if(
       mVertexList[edge.mStartIndex].cbegin(),
       mVertexList[edge.mStartIndex].cend(),
       [&edge](const AdjacentVertex& node) {
           /* Check if the current edge points to edge.mEndIndex */
           return node.mEnd == edge.mEndIndex;
       }
   );
   if (it != mVertexList[edge.mStartIndex].cend()) {
       // Handle situation when you already have this edge in the list
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help